# Work with $_SESSION variables after a jQuery .load() content

Tags: php, jquery

Here my `index.php` page structure:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include("lang/".$_SESSION['lang'].".php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#" data-module="home">
        <div id="content"></div>
    </body>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

I have a piece of `js code` to load the right clicked module.

```
$('a[data-module]').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var module = $(this).attr('data-module');
    $('#content').load('modules/' + module + '.php');
});
```

My problem is:
On each module page, I use `$_SESSION` variables. But with `.load()` jQuery function, it don't works anymore.

Do you have a reason for that ?

Thanks.

Comment: What error do you get? Do all the [moduleName].php files also include the `session_start()` call at the beginning?

Comment: Hello @MarcCompte. I can't include it several time. It will make an error.

Comment: Copy/paste here the errors you find in the console and/or the logs.